# How connect to Local Postgresql server and create database from Python Desktop App

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

How connect to Local Postgresql server and create database from Python Desktop App

my code :

```
import psycopg2

conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='database' user='root' password='root'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

print("Database opened successfully")


conn.close()
print("Database Closed successfully")
```

Comment: What question have you encountered?

Comment: FYI, the single quoted parameters are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these lines after you connect to DB (after line no 4).

```
cursor = conn.cursor();
cursor.execute("create database my_new_database");
```

Full code will look like

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT


conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='postgres' user='root' password='root'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT);

print("Database opened successfully")
cursor = conn.cursor();
cursor.execute("create database my_new_database");

conn.close()

conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_new_database' user='root' password='root'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
# here you need to populate database wit tables "create table mytbl..."
conn.close()
print("Database Closed successfully")
```

Comment: But it connects to a database first Not like that I want it, i want When I install the Python Desktop App Which I made, I want it to connect to postgresql server and then create a database from the program itself

Comment: @siliapps you can connect to "postgres" (postgres is main, default database) database first, then create your database "my_new_database". After that you can disconnect from "postgres" db and connect to "my_new_database".

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you write the code in an orderly manner on it starting from , import psycopg2

Comment: Here is an error message ==>Database opened successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 8, in <module>
    cursor.execute("create database odooo");
psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Comment: You need to set AUTOCOMMIT flag, I just edited the answer.

Comment: It works great
How to override Database if it was existing when running the code again?

Comment: try to connect to my_new_database first, if fail create db, if success start using db.